# Word problem regarding finding torque of a shoulder

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, word-problem

Question: What is the torque about the shoulder if the arm is held in an abducted position at 60 degrees from the body in the frontal plane while holding a 10 kg dumbbell? Assume that the mass of the arm is 6 kg, its center of mass is located 38 cm from the shoulder joint center, and the arm's total length is 80 cm.

The only thing I can think about starting with is the formula for torque, which I believe is $\tau = r \times F \times \sin(\theta).$

Where could I go from here?

Comment: This is probably better suited for Physics Stackexchange but, yeah, you can use $\tau=r\operatorname{x} F\operatorname{x} sin(\theta)$. In particular, since you want to find the torque about the shoulder, treat the dumbell as a single downward force (it's a weight) acting at 80cm from the shoulder- treat the weight of the whole arm as a single force (weight) of 6*g N at 38cm from the shoulder. So you've got these two downward forces of known magnitudes at known distances, both at an angle 60 degrees (from what I've understood). Now just plug and chug for each torque and add the two together.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture:
[image]

$T = rF\sin\theta$ is the apropriate formula.  but, we have two masses and two distances referenced

$T = r_1F_1\sin\theta+ r_2F_2\sin\theta$

Comment: Okay, lemme try this out. So $r_1 = 38$, $F_1 = 6$, $r_2 = 42$, $F_2 = 10$, and both $sin(\theta) = 60^\text{o}$, right?

Comment: Torque is usually measured in Newton meters.  You will want to convert centimeters to meters.  Distances should be measured from shoulder.  $r_2 = 0.8 m,  F$ is a unit of force.  $10kg$ is a unit of mass.  You will need to multiply by the gravitational constant to get $F$